# How to randomize an array without duplicating an integer

Tags: php, for-loop, random

For example if we have this:

```
<?php
$b = array(100);
for ($i = 1; $i <= 100; $i++) {
    $b[$i]=$i;
}
?>
```

How do we randomize all the numbers without duplicating them?

Comment: [shuffle](http://php.net/manual/en/function.shuffle.php) ?

Comment: Remove the `$b = array(100)`; and change to `$b = array();`  You are declaring it wrong (or you want two 100 entries.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your approach will work if you shuffle the array:

```
for ($i = 1; $i <= 100; $i++) {
    //$b = array(100); //why is this even here?
    $b[$i] = $i;
}
shuffle($b);
```

However it's much simpler:

```
$b = range(1, 100);
shuffle($b);
```